# Why does my list of PropertyInfo shows count=0

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class called "summoners" with properties :

```
public string Name;
public string Id;
public int summonerLevel;
public string division;

public string tier;
public int leaguePoints;
```

To debug, i wanted to create a `List<PorpertyInfo>` and store every property name in it, i have :

```
        public void listProperties()
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> t = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (var attr in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            t.Add(attr);
        }
    } //-> breakpoint
```

I placed a brakepoint and it tells me that there is no value in "t"

Comment: because those aren't properties, they are fields

Comment: Can i enumerate fields ?

Comment: Yes, there is a `GetFields()` method like there is a `GetProperties()`.